# Running animation loop is weird (see video) (c#)

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, animation

Whenever my character runs, it has this weird loop, I asked other people and I checked tutorials. I could not find it. See video for more information.

Video:

[Video](https://streamable.com/m5hgbw)

Code:

```
public GameObject thePlayer;
public bool isRunning;
public float horizontalMove;
public float verticalMove;

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal") || Input.GetButton("Vertical"))
    {
        thePlayer.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Run");
        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150;
        verticalMove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 8;
        isRunning = true;
        transform.Rotate(0, horizontalMove, 0);
        transform.Translate(0, 0, verticalMove);
    }
    else
    {
        thePlayer.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Idle");
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that could be that you get the component each frame instead of just getting it once. That could cause problems.
Try doing this:

```
void Start()
{
     anim = thePlayer.GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```

and then play it in the Update function like this:

```
anim.Play("Run");
```

and then in your else statement, do the same with Idle just to make sure:

```
anim.Play("Idle");
```

Comment: I got it working but now it says there is no animator attached to the object (character)

Comment: @Jibbe Double check if there's a animator attacked to the player obviously. If it is, then please post your script again via hatebin

Comment: Since I last checked, it says an error again. Here is the script:https://hatebin.com/vgacbmtkgv

Comment: @Jibbe Alright so I tweaked the script for you:
https://hatebin.com/amdqjfecvm 
Let me know if that helps. Also please specify what kind of error, the more infos we got the more we can help

Comment: I got an error again, It says: The name 'anim' does not exist in the current context
I don't know what it means